# Reducing If conditions in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `item` table as below (SQL Server 2008)

```
Id  Name    Price
------------------
1   A        5
2   B        3
3   A        NULL
4   B        4
```

I'm writing a stored procedure to get items for the name and price. My parameters are

```
@Name nvarchar(255)
@Price float
```

If the user passes the exact name and price I can get top 1 matching from the table.

But if user passes exact name and price not in the table, I need to get the top 1 name matching and NULL price record.

If there's no any NULL price one need to take top 1 Name matching one without considering the price.

```
eg.
@Name = A
@Price = 5

Result Id = 1

@Name = A
@Price 6

Result Id = 3

@Name = B
@Price =5

Result Id = 2
```

Within my stored procedure I have written few `If` conditions to get the above result. Is there any way to get the above without many `if` conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `order by` and `top (1)`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where t.name = @name
order by (case when price = @price then 1
               when price is null then 2
               else 3
          end);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient to test for results, but this SQL will give you what you want:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(1)= 'A';
DECLARE @price INT= 6;

-- tbl is the raw table
WITH tbl
     AS (
     SELECT 1 id, 'A' name, 5 price
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 id, 'B' name, 3 price
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 id, 'A' name, NULL price
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 id, 'B' name, 4 price)
     -- *********************
     -- Solution starts here
     -- *********************
     SELECT id, name, price
         FROM     tbl
     WHERE   name = @name
             AND price = @price
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id, name, price
    FROM     tbl
     WHERE   name = @name
             AND price IS NULL
             AND @price IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TOP 1 id, name, price                 
     FROM         tbl
     WHERE        name = @name
                  AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT NULL
                    FROM   tbl
                    WHERE  name = @name
                           AND price = @price
                );
```